# 2 Motors functioning unevenly - right motor gets more power than the left

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I'm trying to execute this piece of code to run 2 motors on my robot. The code is really simple it's just repetitive.

For some reason that I can't figure out, the motors run unevenly. Here is the code for the testing file:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import motor2

print("directions: ")
print("f = go forward\n")
print("b = go backward\n")
print("l = go left\n")
print("r = go right\n")
print("s = stop\n")
print("q = to exit program\n")

try:
    while True:
                direction = input("Please enter the  direction you want to go, e.g: f ")
                print('You entered', direction)
                if direction == 'q':
                    quit() 
                t = int(input("Please enter the power the wheels\n"))
                if direction == 'f':
                    motor2.forward(t)
                elif direction == 'b':
                    motor2.backward(t)
                elif direction == 'r':
                    motor2.turnright(t)
                elif direction == 'l':  
                    motor2.turnleft(t)
                elif direction == 's':
                    motor2.stopMotor(t) 

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('key board interrupted!')

finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

This is motor2.py: the file that it refers to:

```py
def init():

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(20,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT)

def forward(tf):
    init()
    p1 = GPIO.PWM(20,50)
    p2 = GPIO.PWM(16,50)

    p1.start(30)
    p2.start(30)

    GPIO.output(20, True)
    GPIO.output(27, True)
    GPIO.output(21, False)

    GPIO.output(13, False)
    GPIO.output(3, True)
    GPIO.output(16, True)

    time.sleep(tf)
    GPIO.cleanup()

def backward(tf):
    init()
    p1 = GPIO.PWM(20,50)
    p2 = GPIO.PWM(16,50)

    p1.start(30)
    p2.start(30)

    GPIO.output(20, False)
    GPIO.output(27, True)
    GPIO.output(21, True)

    GPIO.output(13, True)
    GPIO.output(3, True)
    GPIO.output(16, False)

    time.sleep(tf)
    GPIO.cleanup()

def turnright (tf):
    init()
    p1 = GPIO.PWM(21,50)
    p2 = GPIO.PWM(16,50)

    p1.start(50)
    p2.start(50)

    GPIO.output(20, False)
    GPIO.output(27, True)
    GPIO.output(21, True)

    GPIO.output(13, False)
    GPIO.output(3, True)
    GPIO.output(16, True)

    time.sleep(tf)
    GPIO.cleanup()

def turnleft(tf):
    init()
    p1 = GPIO.PWM(21,50)
    p2 = GPIO.PWM(16,50)
    p1.start(50)
    p2.start(50)

    GPIO.output(20, True)
    GPIO.output(27, True)
    GPIO.output(21, True)

    GPIO.output(13, True)
    GPIO.output(3, True)
    GPIO.output(16, False)

    time.sleep(tf)
    GPIO.cleanup()

def stopMotor(tf):
    init()
    GPIO.output(16, False)
    GPIO.output(20, False)
    time.sleep(tf)
```

The pin numbers have been entered correctly and the wiring has been checked. Any and everytime I run this the right motor gets more power than the left. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what happens when you interchange the motors

Comment: Well, all motors are unique, even same brand, same model, same grade, same production/quality assurance.  Jamaica motors usually run faster than Hongkong.  One work around is to use PWM to balance out.  You may like to read projects.rpi.org to find a good tutorial use L298N motor driver, where they suggest you to use PWM to turn or move motor in a straight line or a square.  GPIO ZERO also shows you how to PWM a motor to do similar tricks.  MagPi84 has a good tutorial on DIY L298N dual motor.  Page 44 has another good tutorial to use PWM to move servo (also L298N motor). / to continue, ...

Comment: That Page 44 tutorial demos how to use a PCA9685 16 channel PWM module to move 16 servos (actually can also do L298N motors) and BNO055 9DOF MEMS gyro/accelero/magneto absolute orientation module to sense direction etc.  So you have a gyro/accelero/magneto to help your buddy to move in a perfect straight line (well, almost straight, perhaps 0.1 degree per metre), all done using newbie friendly circuitPython. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101095/rpi4b-raspbian-10-buster-circuit-python-blinka-installation-problem

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of reasons why one side might turn faster than the other.  Unless there is an obvious problem turning the wheel by hand there is probably nothing wrong with the motor.

The normal approach would be to vary the amount of power you send to each motor by changing the PWM dutycycle.  Provide a higher dutycycle for the slower motor.