# Scanner only works if used as root

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+

I am having difficulties getting my scanner to operate. I am using Raspbian Buster on a raspberry pi 3b+. My scanner is a USB Canon LIDE 110, which is connected to the pi through a powered USB hub.

The issue I am having is that I can't seem to use the scanner without root. If I try

```
scanimage -L
```

it doesn't detect it, but

```
sudo scanimage -L
```

returns

> device `genesys:libusb:001:008' is a Canon LiDE 110 flatbed scanner

Likewise if I run `xsane`, it doesn't detect the scanner, but running it with `sudo` brings up the GUI and everything proceeds as normal. However the images I save are only accessible to root.

I have added myself to the scanner group, which doesn't seem to have changed anything, and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: How did you add yourself to the group? Did you log out and in after it?

Comment: The following thread might help. The OP has a mirror problem: his program runs OK non sudo, but does not run sudo: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101315/no-module-named-adafruit-circuitpython-servokit

Comment: jake - i added myself to the scanner group by the following command "sudo usermod -a -G scanner pi"  have logged out and in several times, as well as rebooted the pi numerous times. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Check your scanner's "idVendor" and "idProduct" values with a `lsusb` command. Add a udev rule

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1908", MODE="0664", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

Reload udev with `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`.

Add your userid (I'm assuming you're logging in as pi) to the scanner group `sudo groupadd scanner` and  `sudo usermod -a -G scanner pi` and you should be able to access the scanner without needing sudo.

Plug your scanner in and it should work. Note: I've not tested this.

Comment: if you could clarify a few things for me, I would appreciate it; I am a beginner at using linux.How do I add a udev rule? Did I do it properly? 

this is what I did. I  cd to /etc/udev/rules.d/, and then I created a file with the following: 
, ATTRS[idProduct}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1909", MODE="0664", GROUP="scanner", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

which i saved as canoscan.rules
Then I followed the other steps. 
Following these steps exactly does not seem to have solved the problem; xsane still cannot find the scanner unless I run it as root. Did I do something incorrectly?

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/tutorial-on-how-to-write-basic-udev-rules-in-linux has more detail than I can fit in a StackOverflow comment